# Is it possible to make a call to a C# application from a C++ application?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

I'm a programming student, and I've now had two classes in C#, this semester I'm taking my first C++ class.

Out of curiosity, is it possible to call a C# application from a C++ application?

If so, is it also possible to check if the computer running the program has the .NET framework?

I'm just curious, and I think if its possible, it would be a great little program to write and have as a tool for the future.

Just for your information, here's what I'd like to do:

- Check to see if .NET framework is installed on the computer
- If it's not, ask the user if they would like to install it, and if they would, proceed to download and install the framework
- Call my program written in C# and then kill the C++ program

Comment: It'd be better to ask separate questions, since there are multiple, semi-unrelated questions here...

Comment: Call as in *execute* or call as in *interprocess communication*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Out of curiosity, is it possible to call a C# application from a C++ application?

Yes.  There are a few options here.  If you use C++/CLI, you can use types defined in C# directly from within C++.  Otherwise, a typical approach is to use COM, esposing your C# types as COM objects.

> If so, is it also possible to check if the computer running the program has the .NET framework?

Yes.  Here, typically, you'd just install the framework along with your application.  Here's a page that [shows a few options for checking which version of .NET (if any) is installed](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/05/16/how-to-check-net-framework-version-installed/).

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to call .Net code from C#.

You can expose a class using COM Interop, or you can make a "bridge" using C++/CLI.

You can do it in "raw" C++ (without COM) by [exporting methods from the C# DLL](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

However, in your case, you might as well simply launch the C# EXE file using `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

A C# (actually .NET) application is really a unmanaged stub exe that loads the .NET environment and then jumps into the C# code.

In other words, a C# app is always contained within an unmanaged process.  So if you are willing to restrict yourself to using C# DLLs rather than C# applications you can host them in
your own C++ process.

- Check to see if .NET framework is installed on the computer
- If it's not, ask the user if they would like to install it, and if they would, proceed to download and install the framework
- Initialize the .NET runtime, load my C# library into it and jump into the C# code.
- profit

Note the difference here is that you never shut down the C++ process, it becomes the host for your C# code - this is basically what Windows does anyway when you run a C# application.